# Is it possible to get Laravel user data from Vue JS?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue.js

i have a `Laravel 5.4` application where i do all **Authentication** based logic through PHP and then redirect the user to a `catchAll` route when they are authenticated, and let `VueRouter` take it from there...

I'd like to also use [Entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) because my app will have several types of users and some elements (like an Edit User button) will only be visible to some user Roles.
I might also want to implement specific permissions, like some Admins can edit user Permissions, while others do not.

The issue is, alright i'm in Javascript territory now, so how do i know what my current Auth user is? Setting a global JS variable for `Auth::user` doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Perhaps i would instead pass just an ID, but how exactly without making it globally visible as a `window` variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may create an `auth/check` API call, like this:

```
protected function check()
{
    if(Auth::guard('api')->check()) {
        return Auth::guard('api')->user();
    }

    return ['success' => false];;
}
```

And then get current user with this call.

Comment: Yes @PetrReshetin i guess that will have to do, there's no wrapper for that kind of stuff yet.